How to fetch minimum and maximum stock prices of multiple ticker in a defined period using Yahoo finance in Python?
I'm trying to retrieve the minimum and maximum stock price of ticker in a defined period (start_date = "2024/01/22", end_date = "2024/05/20"). I don't know how to fetch minimum and maximum stock price of multiple tickers. I want to generate the data in excel table like below.



Ticker
Minimum
Maximum




MSFT
388.02
433.60


AMZN
155.61
191.69


META
393.04
531.48



I have tried the code below to find minimum price using List min() method and it is working for one stock. But I don't how to use the ticker_list array in for loop. It would very helpful if anybody can guide me. And also if there is any better way to do this. Thank You.
import yfinance as yahooFinance
import datetime
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_data
ticker_list = ['MSFT', 'AMZN', 'META']

msft_monthly= get_data("msft", start_date = "2024/01/22", end_date = "2024/05/20", index_as_date = True, interval = "1mo")
List1=msft_monthly.low
print(min(List1))


pandas has convenient functionality for constructing Excel files which you can use like this:
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_data
import pandas as pd

ticker_list = ["MSFT", "AMZN", "META"]

start = "2024/01/22"
end = "2024/05/20"

data = []

for ticker in ticker_list:
    result = get_data(
        ticker, start_date=start, end_date=end, interval="1mo"
    )
    d = {
        "Ticker": ticker,
        "Minimum": min(result.low),
        "Maximum": max(result.high),
    }
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel("foo.xlsx", float_format="%.2f", index=False)


Something like this should help:
values = {}
for ticker in ticker_list:
    items_monthly = get_data(ticker, start_date = "2024/01/22", end_date = "2024/05/20", index_as_date = True, interval = "1mo")
    List1=items_monthly.low
    minmax = [min(List1), max(List1)]
    values[ticker] = minmax
print(values)

You should then end up with a dictionary values that looks like:
{'MSFT': [8, 43], 'AMZN': [44, 123], 'META': [81, 443]}

The numbers you see there are dummy values that I put in.
